# How do I link my CSS to the HTML file in Github Pages?

Tags: html, css, github

I need some help here.. I tried different links but it does not load the CSS file..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="https://github.com/cengizkirazjs.github.io/cengizkiraz.github.io/styles.css">
```

This is the page and the outcome: https://cengizkirazjs.github.io/cengizkiraz.github.io/

Any advice? Its my first time linking CSS with HTML on Github!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You need to link to the stylesheet’s Github pages URL, not to the URL of the HTML document for the page on Github about the file you want to link to. (Use a relative path, not an absolute URL).

Comment: Its in the same repositorie as the HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said in the comments, what do you think about changing file path a bit?

In your code we have this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cengizkiraz.github.io/styles.css">
```

It contains an absolute path. If you want to stick to this method, maybe just add a protocol, like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cengizkiraz.github.io/styles.css">
```

But it would be better if you use [relative paths](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-file-paths.html)

In this case, our `<link>` will look like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

It means that HTML will search for this file in folder, where .html file is saved. Looks slightly better, doesn't it?

Comment: The relative path worked! Thank you!